# Installing Mercurial on Centos 6

Tags: mercurial, centos, centos6

I am trying to install mercurial 2.2 on CentOs 6.3, however I feel that repository of centos is a bit outdated because of which it yum installation always shows that your mercurial is up to date.

Now searched some forum and found some other repository to update mercurial client by using following command and repository:

**

> rpm -Uvh
>   http://pkgs.repoforge.org/mercurial/mercurial-2.2.2-1.el6.rfx.i686.rpm

**

However it results in following error:

> hg = 1.4-3.el6 is needed by (installed) emacs-mercurial-1.4-3.el6.i686
>
> hg = 1.4-3.el6 is needed by (installed) mercurial-hgk-1.4-3.el6.i686

I think due to some package dependency, I am not able to install.

Any help/pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

From the Blog: [Install Mercurial Centos 6 VPS Mercurial 2.2.2 Centos 6.4 setup](http://www.sahilsaid.com/blog/install-mercurial-centos-6-4-vps-server-setup/)

> This the only package you're able to install because other RPM packages require python 2.4 whereas Centos 6 has python 2.6 installed.

```
rpm -Uvh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/mercurial/mercurial-2.2.2-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm
```

Test your install:

```
[root@~]# hg version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.2.2)
(see http://mercurial.selenic.com for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2012 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Following this guide to [Installing Mercurial Linux .rpm files with Yum](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download#Linux_.28.rpm.29) works with the latest Hg 3.9 versions too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to uninstall an older (1.4.3) version of Mercurial. Or at least get rid of the emacs-mercurial and mercurial-hgk packages first.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -e "[mercurial.selenic.com]\nname=mercurial.selenic.com\nbaseurl=https://www.mercurial-scm.org/release/centos\$releasever\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0" > /etc/yum.repos.d/mercurial.selenic.com.repo \ 
&& yum install -y mercurial
```

As described [in the mercurial wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download). Although, as `gpgcheck=0` is kind of evil, I'd skip it if possible.